# Energy Harvesting application capacitor selection

Tags: capacitor, low-power, energy-harvesting

I have an energy harvesting application and I want to use a capacitor to store energy. Due to the application being very low power, a capacitor of around 50uF might be enough. What is really important though, is to have the lowest discharge possible, since the charging of the capacitor might be happening over a long period.
What type of capacitor is best suited for this case?

Comment: I suggest that you have a look what is commonly used. Texas Instruments takes energy harvesting seriously so have a look at: http://www.ti.com/solution/other-energy-harvesting and see how they do it.

Comment: Why not use a rechargeable battery to harvest the energy?

Comment: @Leoman12: I am trying to exactly that using a LTC3588 and small piezo elements. How would you arrange circuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a capacitor with a high leakage resistance. A 50uF electrolytic capacitor is inexpensive and easy to find, but has a lower leakage resistance than other types of capacitors. You haven't mentioned the required voltage. That is an important consideration.

Here is a chart of capacitor technologies vs. leakage resistance:

[image: Capasitor Technology vs. Leakage Resistance]

The words "Values of" in the caption appear to be an error. The image is from page 8 of [KEMET Corporation, *Introduction to Capacitor Technologies* Copyright 2013](https://sh.kemet.com/Lists/TechnicalArticles/Attachments/6/What%20is%20a%20Capacitor.pdf)

Here is a chart showing the capacitance and voltage availability for several capacitor technologies.
[image]

Image from: EPCI; ESA SPCD 2018 Symposium via https://epci.eu/capacitors-news-and-trends/

Comment: A chart or additional information about voltages and capacitance values of each capacitor technology would complete the picture nicely.

Comment: The document linked above has a similar chart showing "values of capacitors by dielectric." I will see what I can find about voltage ratings vs. capacitor type.

Comment: Here is a site that has a lot of information about capacitors http://www.iequalscdvdt.com